# Can I redraw a View without forcing a redraw of the underlying View?

Tags: android, view

I have a large custom View (a map) and a smaller View (an altimeter) drawn on top.

[image]

Is there any way to update the top View without forcing a complete redraw of the bottom View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible (in the normal sense). When you have multiple views on top of each other, calling `invalidate()` on one view will redraw all those views. When `invalidate()` is called on a view, it redraws anything that lies in the `dirty region`. This is taken care by the `dispathDraw()` method in the the `ViewGroup`. `dispatchDraw()` inturn calls `drawChild()` and that's why when we call `invalidate()` on one view, other views also gets drawn.

That being said, you could override the `dispatchDraw()` method in your own custom `ViewGroup` and handle how things should behave.

Comment: Thanks. I'm experimenting with making the lower view a subclass of RelativeLayout so that the overlay views are handled directly by it. Overriding dispatchDraw() is definitely do-able.

Comment: Sigh. Just looked at the source code to `dispatchDraw()` -- it's way more complicated than I'm willing to override. I wish there was simply a way to say "invalidate this view but no others."

Comment: Update: it **is** possible if the View has an opaque background. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Also: I just discovered that if you give the View an opaque background, invalidating it won't invalidate the underlying View. It's not a perfect solution, but it's a pretty good one.

Now I need to see if it's possible to make a View with a non-rectangular shape.